# multiple pusher calling Pusher.js

Tags: jquery, cakephp, pusher

When i try to send a json response via the pusher debug console I am getting the response twice in my application. Also on checking the debugger it shows the pusher is making multiple calls to with data as ping/pong. Also each call pusher does is either repeated twice or thrice. I have declared only single instance of pusher call but still it is getting called multiple time. Could anyone help.

I have added the sample of how the ping/pong call is sometimes called twice.

Thanks,

Comment: Pusher sends `Ping` messages to the client in order to verify that it is active. If client is active, Pusher server expects it to reply with `Pong`.[more](http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol#ping-pong) I dont think this might be the cause for your problem.

Comment: Hi, I work for Pusher. You shouldn't be seeing messages duplicate unless you're either sending them multiple times (accidentally) or you have multiple subscriptions to the same channel (again, accidentally). Could you show me the code you're using to subscribe to the channel which is receiving messages multiple times?